# Is this possible in python if run in cmd?

Tags: python

If you have idea about linux bash, we can provide arguments in the same line in the terminal.

For Example in sed, the format is,

```
sed OPTIONS... [SCRIPT] [INPUTFILE...]
```

Let's say, to greet 'Hello' there is a python program, greet.py

```
Input in cmd (Suppose, my python file is reg. in env. path)
==========
greet Arun

Output
======
Hello Arun
```

Wondering, whether this is possible in python, any idea how to?

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, you might have tried putting something like `python read command line` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+read+command+line). In fact, just about anything even vaguely related should work in a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [click](https://github.com/pallets/click) for commandline tools. Have a look at their [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/).

Here is an example of how it works:

hello.py:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("--count", default=1, help="Number of greetings.")
@click.option("--name", prompt="Your name", help="The person to greet.")
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for _ in range(count):
        click.echo(f"Hello, {name}!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

commandline usage:

```
$ python hello.py --count=3
Your name: Click
Hello, Click!
Hello, Click!
Hello, Click!
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is possible with the `sys` library. in the `sys.argv` list it is present a list of the arguments passed to the `python` command. For example:

```
# This is greet.py
import sys
name = sys.argv[1]
print("Hello ", name)
```

So if you run `python greet.py James` it will print `Hello James`